# How can i code this function for take the value of article?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, target

Tentei capturar o valor de um article usando uma função de click e setando a variável, mas o valor da variável não altera, permanece sempre o mesmo. Como posso resolver?

```
import api from '../../services/api';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './home.css'


export default function Home(){
const [filmes, setFilmes] = useState([]);
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

    useEffect(()=>{
        async function loadFilmes(){
            const response = await api.get('movie/now_playing?', {
                params:{
                    api_key:'myApiKey123456',
                    language: 'pt-BR',
                    page: 1,
    
                }
            })
            setFilmes(response.data.results);
        }
        loadFilmes();
        console.log(filmes);
        
    },[]);


    return(
        <div>
            <h1>teste → {title}</h1>
            <div className="slider">
                {filmes.map(filme=>{
                    return(<article key={filme.id} value={filme.title} onClick={e=>setTitle(e.target.value)}>
                        <h3>{filme.title}</h3>
                        <img className='poster' src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${filme.poster_path}`} alt={filme.title}/>
                    </article>)
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: First: please ask your question in English, it is easier to understand and answer.  Second, never, never, never, never show your credentials like API_key or password or other sensible data.

Answer (score 0):

`article` tag hasn't `value` attribute.
So if you reach your purpose, change the `article` tag to the `button` or ...

Anyway, you should change it to the tag which has `value` attribute.

Or, you should change your code like this:

```
return(<article key={filme.id} onClick={setTitle(filme.title)}>
          <h3>{filme.title}</h3>
          <img className='poster' src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${filme.poster_path}`} alt={filme.title}/>
       </article>)
```

Good luck.